# Dojo JsonRest Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo, basic-authentication

I want to read JSON Data from a REST-Service with the Dojo JsonRest. The REST-Service requires Username and Password as Basis Authentication String. For the beginning, I hardcoded this string. Now, I tried the following:

```
    var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://host/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=gonzo", 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false,
    user: "test",
    password: "test"
    });
```

But this did not work. Therefore my question: How can I send basic authentication credentials with Dojo JsonRest?

Comment: You may be able to put the username and password into the target url like this:  "http://username:password@host/activiti-blahblahblah".  Using the username:password@domain.com after the http:// could work.

Comment: Also, if the username is an email address, the the @ symbol in the address should be replaced first with "%40" before putting it into the link:  myemail%40whatever.com:password@domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try one of two things:

1)  Put the username and password in the target url itself like so:

```
var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://username:password@host/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=gonzo", 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false
});
```

If the username is an email address, then:

```
var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://useremail%40whatever.com:password@host/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=gonzo", 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false
});
```

2)  Use the header propery of JsonRest:

```
var encodedLogin = "Basic " + window.btoa("username:password");
var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://host/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=gonzo", 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false,
    headers: {
        Authorization: encodedLogin
    }
});
```

This solution use base64 encoding on the username and password combination string and then sends it with the "Authorization" header parameter.